# How can i integrate GroovyConsole to in my java swing app?

Tags: java, swing, groovy, groovy-console

I have a Java swing app. I want to use groovy.console.ui.Console (GroovyConsole) in my app. I can run groovy console but it opens in a new window. It should be in my frame.

I tried to add output and input panel in new JPanels but it is not enough and also console runs in a new window.

Comment: Is it designed to be reused in that way? Maybe not